# How to create a Pin Keyboard on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, authentication

I wonder how to create a pin keyboard like this layout, in this layout, we have a pinview and Pin keyboard just and, I still looking on GitHub but they using a library not made the layout by self, maybe someone can help me to solve this case, thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy.
You can use this
https://github.com/davidmigloz/number-keyboard

Or you can design this by adding buttons to your layout.